# skipUntil and flatMap with concurrency 1 hangs in Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor, flatmap

I have experienced a strange behavior in Reactor (v. 3.4.2) when using `skipUntil` and `flatMap(fn, concurrency)` operators with `concurrency=1`. The pipeline hangs.

To demonstrate what I mean here is a short example that works as I would expect:

```
Flux.range(1, 5)
    .skipUntil(v -> v > 1)
    .flatMap(v -> Mono.just(v))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .blockLast();
```

It prints `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` to a separate line. However, if I add a concurrency argument equal to `1` to the `flatMap` operator then the execution hangs:

```
Flux.range(1, 5)
    .skipUntil(v -> v > 1)
    .flatMap(v -> Mono.just(v), 1)
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .blockLast();
```

I don't know if I missed something or there is some erroneous behavior of `skipUntil` that after it skips the first item it does not request next from the upstream. Is the second example valid?

Comment: this is indeed a bug, thanks for opening https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2578